# How can i fix it java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception, parseint

```
public class Ip_to_uint32 {

    public static int main(String ip) {
        String[] x = ip.split("[.]");
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            binary.append(binaryform(Integer.parseInt(x[i])));
        }
        String correct = binary.toString();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(correct);
        return n;
    }

    public static String binaryform(int in) {
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(in);
        if (binary.length() != 8){
            StringBuilder correctLegth = new StringBuilder();
            int difference = 8 - binary.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++){
                correctLegth.append("0");
            }
            return String.valueOf(correctLegth.append(binary));
        }
        return binary;
    }
```

It gives me this error:

````
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)

at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

at it.edu.itiszuccante.Ip_to_uint32.main(Ip_to_uint32.java:14)

at it.edu.itiszuccante.Ip_to_uint32Test.main(Ip_to_uint32Test.java:12)```
````

Can't convert string to number, can someone help me ??

(Added from author's comment:)

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000001000000000101000000001" under radix 2
```

Comment: It looks like you have an ip address passed to main not sure though. Show us what exactly you are passing. That will help understand the input you pass...

Comment: Please show the complete stacktrace rather than lines starting with `at`

Comment: You can use debugger to actually see what values are set to variables. That may hive you clues.

Comment: You may wanna specify that you're parsing an unsigned int, and that the input is in base 2: int n = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(correct, 2);

Comment: @Vinay 

`import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Ip_to_uint32Test {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Assert.assertEquals(Ip_to_uint32.main("128.32.10.1"), "2149583361");
        /*Assert.assertEquals(AlphaNumNumAlpha.main("18zyz14"), "r262526n");
        Assert.assertEquals(AlphaNumNumAlpha.main("a1b2c3d4"), "1a2b3c4d");
        Assert.assertEquals(AlphaNumNumAlpha.main("5a8p17"), "e1h16q");*/
    }
}`

Comment: The complete stacktrace should include a message just prior to your trace as in "Exception in thread..." and for the NFE would include the "For input string" - this is what @OneCricketeer had asked.

Comment: @Andy 
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000001000000000101000000001" under radix 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid range for `int` is from `-0b10000000_00000000_00000000_00000000` to `0b1111111_11111111_11111111_11111111` but the string being parsed is `"10000000001000000000101000000001"` (one additional bit - the sign bit). 
This is valid as an unsigned `int`, not a primitive type in Java, but it can be parsed using:

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt(correct, 2)
```

(It could also be parsed as a `long` and converted (cast) to an `int`)
(there is no unsigned int in Java, all IPs starting with `128` or greater will result in a negative `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

add an additional validation for  checking whether string is a number (like NAN) before converting string to number  to avoid the  exception

Comment: Yes, it doesn't take it as a number but I'm sure it's a number, that's the problem